# How to replace unix sort plus-notation with -k?

Tags: unix

This is probably dead simple, but I can't get it to work. How do I correct this `sort` notation

`sort +0 -1 something`

to use more POSIX-compliant `-k` notation? If I try `sort -k 0,1 something`, `sort` just tells me

```
sort: field number is zero: invalid field specification `0,1'
```

I can't find it in sort documentation anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually simple - I do not need the 0-th field in `-k` notation. So, to `+0 -1`, `-k 1` is an equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
sort -k1,2 something
```

I don't have a unix-like system on hand that allows the +0 and -1 notation, but my guess is you're looking to sort on maybe the first and second fields? The indices used in the -k flag are one-based, not zero-based, so I think you have the right idea and just need to change your 0,1 to a 1,2.

Comment: The +0 -1 actually sort it by the FIRST field. Which is exactly what -k1 does. It was simpler than I thought. :)